# BDD Bank OCR Kata with Cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

I am a newbie to Ruby and BDD. I am attempting to solve the [Bank OCR Kata] (http://codingdojo.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?KataBankOCR) using BDD with cucumber and I got stuck at the very first step . Since the Kata uses "|" and multi line string as inputs. How do I provide this input to the scenario outline. I am trying to build a Feature like

```
Scenario Outline: submit account number
   Given the scanner is ready
   When  the account number is "<account>"
   Then the response should be "<response>"

Scenarios: read account
   |account| response |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%q()` to quote multiple lines.

```
my_lines = %q(This text
spans multiple
lines)
```

Which will allow you to write something like

```
%q(  _  _     _  _  _  _  _
  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_|
  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _| )
```

which I believe is the the same as `123456789`

**Note**

my spacing may be off on the actual input.